# RESTful service unable to return proper JSON format

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest

My resource is given as follows, I am trying to return all the documents in the mongo table in a json format.

```
@Path("/myresource")
@GET
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<DBObject> getMongoObject() throws Exception {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("zapshop");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("admin");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
    DBObject object = cursor.next();
    ArrayList<DBObject> token = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    token.add(object);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        object = cursor.next();
        token.add(object);
        //System.out.println(token);
    }
    if (object == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return token;
}
```

This returns JSON which contains:

```
[{"type":"dbObject"},{"type":"dbObject"}]
```

But when i print out token in the console it contains the proper collection, which is :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55fc4844f7aea67825dae9a1"),
  "login_id" : "sam",
  "password" : "***"
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56110506d7ca91f604065fdc"),
  "login_id" : "bam",
  "password" : "***"
}
```

Which is what i want it to return. Where am i going wrong,pls try providing an example as i am new to RESTful services.

Comment: have you tried `return.toString()` with the `String` as return type of `getMongoObject()`. See [API Docs of BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: you mean public String getMongoObject(){....return token.toString();} ?

Comment: Now that i tried it,it works. wow, how did i miss that. Thank u for the help, this was quite a stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
public String getMongoObject() throws Exception {
    .......
    .......
    return token.toString();
}
```

From the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#toString%28%29):

**toString**

```
public String toString()
```

> Returns a JSON serialization of this object

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
I use GSON to convert from BasicDBObject to my own POJO which is TinyBlogDBObject

TinyBlogDBObject obj = convertJSONToPojo(cursor.next().toString());
private static TinyBlogDBObject convertJSONToPojo(String json){

```
Type type = new TypeToken< TinyBlogDBObject >(){}.getType();

return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
```

}